# XDebug with IISExpress + PHP Tools for Visual Studio

Tags: php, visual-studio-2012, xdebug, iis-express

I have the following setup:

- Visual Studio 2012 with the extension [PHP Tools for Visual Studio](http://www.devsense.com/products/php-tools)
- PHP 5.3
- No IIS, using the integrated IIS Express server for debugging

I have the following entries in my php.ini ([full version on pastebin](http://pastebin.com/eb7EA6M6))

```
[XDEBUG]
xdebug.remote_enable = on
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = localhost
xdebug.remote_port = 9000


[PHP_XDEBUG-2.2.1-5.3-VC9-NTS]
[PHP_XDEBUG-2.2.1-5.3-VC9-NTS]
zend_extension="C:\P(...)es (x86)\PHP\v5.3\ext\php_xdebug-2.2.1-5.3-vc9-nts.dll"
```

I have configured PHP Tools to use port 9000 for debugging. On the XDebug home page I submitted my phpinfo() output and it said there that things were set up correctly.

However, when I try to debug in Visual Studio, nothing happens, i.e. the php file I want to debug loads in the browser without breaking on my breakpoint.

This is the url that I try to debug:

```
http://localhost:16472/index.php?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=1
```

Is there anything special that needs to be done in order for xdebug to work with IIS Express? Or do I have to install IIS or Apache on the computer to get things going?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That was a minor issue with unicode characters in project path which was solved in the later update. Now it's just necesary to update PHP Tools. More details on this [forum](http://support.devsense.com/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=988)

Comment: Thanks for your help on the forums. To be specific, I moved my php project from c:\users\<my username with unicode characters>\etc to c:\projects\blahblah